# Wix bookings use getServiceAvailability( ) and exported to JSON

Tags: api, velo

I created a website that accepts appointments online using wix booking. I already managed to export the appointments with all the details to JSON format.
I am trying to do the same to be able to create the appointments from an external app but for this I want to be able to first obtain getServiceAvailability() from wix-bookings API and I can't find a way to do it. I have tried in all the ways that I know and I do not get any results, I am not a programming expert and that is why I ask for help in this way, if someone who knows wix well and how to work with its API that could help me at least have one basis of how to do it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the availability information from an external service, you can create an HTTP function to expose that information.